# Getting All items from listview xamarin android

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

I am using a listview in xamarin android with custom adapter. I want to get all items of the listview on button click, but it returns only the visible items on the screen. Otherwise it returns null in view object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstview.Count; i++)
{

    View v = lstview.GetChildAt(i - lstview.FirstVisiblePosition);
    if (v != null)
    {
        CheckBox c = (CheckBox)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        TextView tt = (TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.Text2);

        string StudentID = tt.Text;

        l.Add(new SaveAttendanceClass
        {
            Id = StudentID,
            IsPresent = c.Checked
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` only contains `View` objects for the visible part of your list. The object that contains all the items, including the ones not currently on-screen is the `Adapter`.

Iterate over the items in your custom adapter instead of the `View`s in your `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. but how can i get the state of the checkbox. as its not associated with the adapter.